# PDF reader with pdf library

Tags: pdf

I'm just wondering if there is any PDF reader that is capable of remembering documents that I have with some sorting/virtual directory function, that could remember where I have left before closing a particular document so I could return to reading later without need to manually bookmark.

Or if anyone knows about some library/document management software that can keep track of my reading progress automatically i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe Reader has the ability to reopen *individual* documents at the page you finished off at. In `Edit` > `Preferences...` > `Documents`, select `Restore last view settings when reopening documents`. [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/) has a similar feature.

If you are looking to keep track of your progress through multiple documents, then [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) may be useful. It can import documents into its library, and has a column for marking documents as read/unread - when a document is opened this automatically changes to "Marked as read". It can also add tags and notes to documents, and export references.

Comment: On FoxIt, the page is remembered only for somedays, any tips on how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the OS you are using. In Mac, Preview remembers the point at which you had previously closed the document and opens it up for you the next time you open it. Same is the case with document viewer in Ubuntu (linux)..